# Maven Filtering

Tags: filtering, maven-3, android-maven-plugin

I am using Maven (3.x) to build an Android application within Hudson.  I use filtering/profiles to do text substition of the strings.xml file as part of the build.

So within the strings.xml, I will have entries such as:

`<string name="app_name">${app_name}</string>`

Within the pom.xml file, I have profile entries:

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <properties>
            <app_env>local</app_env>
       <app_name>Acme-loc</app_name>
        </properties>
    </profile>  
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <app_env>dev</app_env>
       <app_name>Acme-dev</app_name>
        </properties>
    </profile>      
    ....
```

When I look inside the *.apk, the strings.xml file is substituted correctly.  However, when installed in device, I see ${app_name} which leads me to believe that the substitution is happening after the compile of app.  Can I specify which step of the build the substitution happens?

Comment: Where is strings.xml?  In src/main/resources?  Are you sure it's being consumed at compile phase - not somewhere like generate-sources?

Comment: A Maven/Android project is a bit different.  strings.xml is a required Android artificat that sits in the res/values section.

Comment: In this case, you might have more luck having a "template" strings.xml which has it's contents replaced and placed into res/values. Have a look into maven-replacer-plugin with the outputFile param to archive this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a standard maven build, resource filtering happens at process-resources, which comes before compile, which comes before package. It's hard to say more without more details about how you have resource filtering set up and how your package is built.

**Edit:** It looks like you're probably generating the R.java file using the android plugin's [generate-sources](http://maven-android-plugin-m2site.googlecode.com/svn-history/r18/generate-sources-mojo.html) goal, right? That's most likely bound to the generate-sources phase. Your strings.xml doesn't get filtered until the process-resources phase, which comes [later in the build](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). You need to make sure that the android goal runs *after* the resource filtering happens and that it points at the output strings.xml file, not the source file.

Comment: I have the various environments setup in the pom.xml file and within Hudson, in the Goals and Options line of the Build section, I specified: -Pdev clean package

Comment: I don't know much about Android. The apk is the packaged app, right? You're saying that strings.xml has the right values when you look inside it, but when you run it, it shows the placeholder? That would seem to indicate the strings are being loaded from somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, the *.apk is the package for this build type.  When you build an Android app, that strings.xml file is compiled to an R.java class.  So, when I look into the *.apk file, the strings.xml that is included in there (but I don't believed used) has the correct substitution but the R.java class has a hex value.  When I install it on the phone I see the placeholder, not the value which was leading me to believe that the substitution was happening after the R.java class file was created.

Comment: @Perry: Ah, I get it. The question, then, is, "What creates R.java?" I see reports that either Eclipse or Ant can generate it. What's doing it in your setup?

Comment: @Ryan, I would hope the maven android plugin would be creating the R.java, assuming that's what he is using to build his project.

Comment: Yes, I am using the Maven/Android plugin.

Comment: @Perry: Updated my answer. Check it out.

Comment: That was it.  I altered the maven-resources-plugin to run earlier by giving it an phase/goal befoe the android plugin.

Comment: @PerryHoekstra could you provide a code sample of that?

Answer (score 3):

There is an example of how to apply Maven resource filtering to Android resource files in the [Maven-Android-Plugin samples](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Samples), and also a brief [discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/maven-android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b21500da56b6d980?pli=1) about it.

Specifically have a look at the Morseflash app pom.xml in the samples.

The key points are:-

- run resource filtering during the **`initialize`** phase, putting the output into `/target/filtered-res`
- configure the maven-android-plugin to then pickup it's resources from the filtered resources directory e.g.:

`<resourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/filtered-res</resourceDirectory>`

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing something like that. Within Hudson, my build string looks like this:   `-Pdev -Dandroid-debug=true buildnumber:create process-resources clean package`

Comment: I also had to do the include/exclude *.xml so that the binaries did not come across.